# Trouble accessing attribute after using BeautifulSoup's findAll

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape sites like [this one](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01pzszx)  on the BBC website to grab the relevant parts of the programme listing, and I've just started using BeautifulSoup to do this.

The parts of interest start with sections like:

```
<li about="/programmes/p013zzsl#segment" class="segment track" id="segmentevent-p013zzsm" typeof="po:MusicSegment">

<li about="/programmes/p014003v#segment" class="segment speech alt" id="segmentevent_p014003w" typeof="po:SpeechSegment">
```

What I've done so far is opened the HTML as `soup` and then used `soup.findAll(typeof=['po:MusicSegment', 'po:SpeechSegment'])` to give a ResultSet of the parts I'm interested in the order in which they appear.

What I then want to do is check whether a section refers to `po:MusicSegment` or `po:SpeechSegment` in HTML that looks like:

```
<li about="/programmes/p01400m9#segment" class="segment track" id="segmentevent-p01400mb" typeof="po:MusicSegment"> <span class="artist-image"> <span class="depiction" rel="foaf:depiction"><img alt="" height="63" src="http://static.bbci.co.uk/programmes/2.54.3/img/thumbnail/artists_default.jpg" width="112"/></span> </span> <script type="text/javascript"> window.programme_data.tracklist.push({ segment_event_pid : "p01400mb", segment_pid : "p01400m9", playlist : "http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p01400m9.emp" }); </script> <h3> <span rel="mo:performer"> <span class="artist no-image" property="foaf:name" typeof="mo:MusicArtist">Mala</span> </span> <span class="title" property="dc:title">Calle F</span> </h3></li>
```

I want to access the `typeof` attribute associated with `<li>`, but if this chunk of HTML (as a BS4 tag) is called `section` and I enter `section.li`, it returns `None`.

Note that if I do `section.img` instead, I get something back:

```
<img alt="" height="63" src="http://static.bbci.co.uk/programmes/2.54.3/img/thumbnail/artists_default.jpg" width="112"/>
```

and I could then do, e.g. `section.img['height']` to get back `u'63'`

What I want is something analogous for the `section.li` part, so `section.li['typeof']` to give me `po:MusicSegment` or `po:SpeechSegment`

Of course, I could simply convert each result to text and then do a simple string search, but searching by attribute seems more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd iterate over the list returned by `findAll`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<li about="/programmes/p013zzsl#segment" class="segment track" id="segmentevent-p013zzsm" typeof="po:MusicSegment"><li about="/programmes/p014003v#segment" class="segment speech alt" id="segmentevent_p014003w" typeof="po:SpeechSegment">')

for elem in soup.findAll(typeof=['po:MusicSegment', 'po:SpeechSegment']):
    print elem['typeof']
```

returns

```
po:MusicSegment
po:SpeechSegment
```

and then conditionally perform your other tasks:

```
if elem['typeof'] == 'po:MusicSegment'
    do.something()
elif elem['typeof'] == 'po:SpeechSegment':
    do.something_else()
```

Comment: I was storing the results to an intermediate variable and then processing them; this approach is much simpler.